# Dataframe melt and retain index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace, melt

I have a  dataframe like so:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            ["True", "False"],
            ["True", "True"],
            ["False", "True"],

        ],
        index=["bob", "sue", "joe"],
        columns=["R1", "R2"],
    )
```

I'd like to melt the df so that the index names are used, and replace the Trues with the column name, so the output is like so:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            ["bob", "R1"],
            ["sue", "R1"],
            ["sue", "R2"],
            ["joe", "R2"],
        ],
        columns=["Names", "Role"],
    )
```

How can I achieve  this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with convert index to column first:

```
df = df.rename_axis('Names').reset_index().melt('Names', var_name='Role')
```

And then filter by `True` value:

```
df = df.loc[df['value'].map({'True':True, 'False':False}), ['Names','Role']]
```

Or:

```
df = df.loc[df['value'] == 'True', ['Names','Role']]
```

---

```
print(df)  
  Names Role
0   bob   R1
1   sue   R1
4   sue   R2
5   joe   R2
```